# How is Captain America the first Avenger?

Tags: marvel, avengers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was Captain America called “the first Avenger”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16066/why-was-captain-america-called-the-first-avenger)

Iron Man was a member of the group before he was, and thor is older, so how is he the "first" avenger ?